# how to use grep and mv together in a directory in shell?

Tags: unix, grep, home-directory, mv

how do you grep the contents of all files in a directory for "TEST" then move those files to a different directory(like the home dir.)?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine *grep* and [*find*](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for this task:

```
find SOURCE -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q TEST {} \; -exec mv -i {} DEST \;
```

#### How it works

- `find SOURCE -maxdepth 1 -type f` finds all files (`-type f`) in the directory *SOURCE*.

  If you want to include files in subdirectories as well, just remove `-maxdepth 1`.
- `-exec grep -q TEST {} \;` greps the files, one by one, for the string *TEST*. Here, `{}` is the file that is currently being processed.

  The `-q` switch makes grep "quiet", i.e., it will not output anything. The `-exec` statement will be true if *grep* is successful, i.e., it finds the string.
- `-exec mv -i {} DEST \;` moves a file containing the string *TEST* into the directory *DEST*.

  The `-i` switch make *mv* "interactive", i.e., it will prompt before overwriting other files.

Comment: I have never thought of being able to chain `-exec` like that, so I have learned something today, even though it is still early where I am :-) .

Answer (score 2):

Just another alternative (this requires some GNU specific extensions, though; since you tagged the question "Unix", it might not fit you):

```
grep -lZd skip TEST SOURCE/* | xargs -0I{} mv -i {} DEST
```

- `grep -l`

  prints matching filenames instead of normal output.
- `grep -Z`

  gives null byte separated output, which is a safe bet in handling strange filenames over pipes.
- `grep -d skip`

  defines the `skip` action for encountered directories among the input arguments.

  This is not really needed; it just avoids the notice `grep: SOURCE/DIR: Is a directory` when encountering directories. If you want recursive reading of files in directories, use the action `recurse`, or even shorter just the equivalent `-r` switch (see below point as well).
- `SOURCE/*`

  matches all files in the directory `SOURCE` using shell [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Hidden files are per default not matched; this can be changed by setting `shopt -s dotglob` in Bash before the `grep` command is issued.

  One might be tempted to just add `SOURCE/.*` to the input arguments, but this will have perhaps unexpected consequences if used with `-r` (since we match `.` and `..` as well).

  If recursive matching is wanted, just use `-r SOURCE` without file globbing as the input argument, which includes hidden files in the directory structure.
- `xargs -0`

  interprets the input as null separated.
- `xargs -I{}`

  defines `{}` to be a placeholder for the input argument.
- `mv -i`

  makes the move interactive as per Dennis' suggestion, to avoid mistakes.

To test this pattern (or commands in general), a useful technique is to insert `echo` before the actual command to see which commands are to be executed, i.e. change `mv` to `echo mv`.

Answer (score 0):

$ mv TEST* /path/to/destination

Works for me, hope it works for you. In my case it was:

$ mv note_[5,6]* ~/documents/notes

Which moved note_5_math.pdf and note_6_math.pdf to home/documents/notes directory.

Comment: Hello, this has nothing to do with grep.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They want to move files that **contain** the string `TEST`, (re)read the question.